# How to bind the backspace key in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am just simply trying to bind the backspace key to a tkinter button.

In a different project I was able to bind the return/enter key with this code:

`root.bind('<Return>', validateLogin)`

So I assumed maybe I could do something similar for this project like:

`root.bind('<Backspace>', button_clear)`

But this returns this in command prompt:
_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "backspace"

If you need any more information to help I'd be glad to provide more info. (just not sure on what would be helpful info or not)

Answer (score 2):

Backspace has to be ,so it would be

```
root.bind('<BackSpace>',button_clear)
```

Comment: I just needed to capitalize the S, thank you so much!

Comment: Yep, that's all you needed