# How to press a button when a specific character/number is pressed in keyboard on Python?

Tags: python

i have a simple calculator program that is running in a window  with Tkinter that i called `window = Tk()`, i have created normal buttons but i want that when i press for example "1" the bottun 1 is pressed, as if i clicked the button with the mouse. So how can i detect if the specific number 1 is pressed? Because for now the program prints "Hello" (it's for check that the character detection works) but with any letter/character i press, how to set a specific number for example "1"? Thanks a lot and try to be clear i'm a beginner

```
bottone1= Button(window,text= "1", font= ('Helvetica 20 '),width=6,height=1,bg="#008BC7", command=lambda:button_press(1))

def var (e):
    print("Hello")

window.bind("", var)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you learned about the `bind()` method yet?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Don't assume the user did a "<KeyPress>" if not mentioned explicitly

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria That string ("<KeyPress>") was in the original post - I didn't add it. I just added code fences. But it is not in the edit history. Strange. Maybe we edited simultaneously.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Nope, we did not edit simultaneously. Anyway, no biggie :)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp - SO is notoriously bad with stuff that looks like HTML - with those `<...>` brackets. If you look at the edit history and hit "source" on an entry you can still see it:  https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/c256b214-890d-4c6c-9fbf-94fa2bf2c96a/view-source

Answer (score 2):

You can bind certain keys to a function that takes a `*args` param - in case of the button press with your mouse the parameter will be `None` - if you bind a key it will hold the keyevent:

```
from tkinter import *

def pressMeFunc(*args):
    if args:
        print(args[0].char)  # leverage the keyPressed event fields
    else:
        print("Hello")

window = Tk() 

b = Button(window, text="Press Me", command=pressMeFunc)
b.pack()

window.bind("1",  pressMeFunc)
window.bind("2",  pressMeFunc)
window.bind("3",  pressMeFunc)

window.mainloop()
```

If you start this and press the "2" key, you get in `*args` a KeyPress event:

[image: VS Code Inspect of *args[0] if "2" was pressed]

You can use its `.char` field to get the key pressed.

---

You could create a dictionary with a "key" to "function" mapping and leverage that to call things depending on the key pressed:

```
def one(): 
    print("ONE")

def two(): 
    print ("TWO")

def default_thing(*_):
    print("Hello")

do_stuff_mapping = {"1": one, "2": two}

def pressMeFunc(*args):    
    if args:
        print(args[0].char)
        # get the function as defined above or default one 
        # if key is not mapped to a function - then call it 
        do_stuff_mapping.get(args[0].char, default_thing) ()
    else:
        default_thing(None)
```

Comment: OK thanks Patrick i'm starting to understand something, could you please explain me when i press 1,2 or 3 according with your code, how to ativate the butto without clicking the button with the arrow of the mouse? I wrote the function lambda of the button in my original code

Comment: @Stefano You bind the _same_  function to the button AND the key - in your case mabye `window.bind("1", lambda _: button_press(1))` - `lambda _:,...` because the lambda has to accept the KeyPress event object

Comment: Hey thanks a lot it works!! One last question, why writing the code that you wrote:            
 window.bind("1", lambda _: button_press(1))   it works but writing the lambda syntax of my original code                            
 lambda:button_press("1"))     doesn't work?

Comment: @Stef because for Key-Bindings the lambda needs to take the KeyPressed event as param - using `lambda _: button_press("1")` simply ignores the param the keypress will provide. You could as well use `lambda kpe: button_press(kpe.char)` to automagically get the "char" of the pressed key and feed it to your function

Comment: Ok thanks i will read again all you answers, by the way do you know how to set even the keys "Enter" and "Backspace"?? Because if i try to type them in the keyboard just like "1" for example of course it doesn't work

Comment: @Stefano SO is cool - most problems are solved - just need to search for them:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65816621/how-to-bind-the-backspace-key-in-python      .. `<Return>` should be straight forward

Comment: Ok thanks a lot i solved all my problems, you are a programming master :D